# Multidimensional array with random removal of key values with minimum 1 left

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create an array that I can remove randomly the content for the [id] key where they are the same [parent_id].

This is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 1
            [id] => 286
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 286
            [id] => 142
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 1
            [id] => 287
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 1
            [id] => 288
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 1
            [id] => 289
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 289
            [id] => 140
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 289
            [id] => 143
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 289
            [id] => 242
        )

)
```

I have generated it with the following code:

```
$parentList = array();
foreach ($list as $item) 
{
    $parentList[] = array("parent_id" => $item->parent_id, "id" => $item->id);
}
```

What I can't figure out is how to transform the array into this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 1
            [id] => Array (286, 287, 288, 289) 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 286
            [id] => Array (142)
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 289
            [id] => Array (140, 143, 242)
        )

)
```

After that I would like to only have one id for each parent id left randomly in each [id] array.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the key value in the result don't matter, you're better of using the `parent_id` as the key.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($list as $entry) {
    $parent = $entry['parent_id'];

    // Make the base entry
    if (!array_key_exists($parent, $result)) {
        $result[$parent]['parent_id'] = $parent;
    }

    // Append this entry to the result
    $result[$parent]['id'][] = $entry['id'];
}
```

Edit: If you want to get this result in only a single loop - which I now realise that you probably meant - you can something try this:

```
$parentList = array();
foreach ($list as $item) {
    // Make base entry, if it doesn't exist yet
    if (!array_key_exists($item->parent_id, $parentList)) {
        $parentList[$item->parent_id]['parent_id'] = $item->parent_id;
    }

    // Append the item id to the parent container
    $parentList[$item->parent_id]['id'][] = $item->id;
}
```

Comment: Yes and no, @Jack... The output will be similar. The kind of input is what makes the difference. Code on top is the **first** version I've written, transforming the example array (*array of arrays containing parent and item id*). Afterwards I realised it might be more helpful transforming the other source too, so I wrote the **second** block in the edit. That function is using the original input (*array of objects*) as source, in stead of using the other array. This way, topic starter can pick what suits him (or her?) most.